# Pattern for modular ScriptableObject-Database?

Tags: c#, database, unity-game-engine, design-patterns, persistence

Lets say we want to store game data inside of scriptableObjects and we have plenty of them... So we need to find a way to store them efficiently in a modular way.

What pattern could we use to code a scriptableObject database for providing a substainable base for our game data- scriptableObjects?

And are there any patterns or structures for extending our game data - scriptableObjects in order to construct them modular and flexible aswell ?

Comment: ScriptableObjects are not meant to store data outside of runtime. It sounds like you are asking what pattern to use in order to implement scriptableObjects for data persistence. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the corresponding `.asset` files for a scriptable object in the `Resources` folder, and use the static methods in the `Resources` class to enumerate them  in your code.